# Strage mouse behavior in DraftSight 2015

Tags: 14.04, mouse

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Draft Sight 2015 from [here](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/).

Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series

[Video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36I2zOYKbNA&feature=youtu.be)

I would describe that as a "strange behavior" it is slow but sometime it's not predictable.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: it appears to be a faulty mouse problem. Does it release left button while you hold it down?

Comment: Mouse works perfectly with other software, generally this problem appears when I cross the board between white and black area in DraftSight window